# How to fill a combobox with available filenames

Tags: combobox, selection, filenames

i have direcory with variable amount of files.
When starting a C#-windows-form i want to read out all the filenames of a directory and show them in a dropdown-combobox. The selected filename should then be returned when pressing a button.
How can i do this?
Thank you for the help

Answer (score 0):

Solved:

```
System.IO.DirectoryInfo myPath = new System.IO.DirectoryInfo(myPathIni);
        foreach (System.IO.FileInfo f in myPath.GetFiles())
        {
            comboBox1.Items.Add(f.Name);
        }
```